# Undefined on data.filter or multi if statements with returning array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've figured out the following code allows me to look up multiple variables, and return them in an array...

```
function() {
    var cart_item_1 = document.querySelectorAll("#main>#ViewCartWrapper>form>div>.bordered>tbody>tr>td")[5].innerText;
    var cart_item_2 = document.querySelectorAll("#main>#ViewCartWrapper>form>div>.bordered>tbody>tr>td")[9].innerText;
    var cart_item_3 = document.querySelectorAll("#main>#ViewCartWrapper>form>div>.bordered>tbody>tr>td")[13].innerText;
    return [cart_item_1, cart_item_2, cart_item_3];
}
```

Everything works fine as long as there are exactly  (3) cart items, but the environment that I'm working with varies. There may only be 1 cart item or 7 depending on user input.

Unless there's an exact 3 in this scenario it'll return everything back as undefined.

I've tried using:

```
    if ([cart_item_1] == undefined){
    return "_"
    } 
    else {
    return [cart_item_1]
    }
    if ([cart_item_2] == undefined){
    return "_"
    } 
    else {
    return [cart_item_2]
    }
```

etc...

But it'll stop after the first cart item.

I tried implementing a data.filter from another post "removing-undefined-values-from-array" but it returned everything back as undefined.

Can someone help with what I need to look for to return back only variables that exist?

Or looking at the cart code, is there a better way of dynamically pulling any instance of the:

```
document.querySelectorAll("#main>#ViewCartWrapper>form>div>.bordered>tbody>tr>td")**[5]**.innerText
```

The only thing that changes is the number bolded. I tried using a wildcard in that field but it returned back undefined.

Since I'm using for GTM as a custom js variable then any recommendation has to of course be js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the elements and only push the 'innerText' of the ones you need in an array:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#main>#ViewCartWrapper>form>div>.bordered>tbody>tr>td");

var texts = [];
for(var i =0;i<elements.length;i++) {
  if(i==5||i==7||i==10) {
    texts.push(elements[i].innerText);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Carl thanks for the edit. I am on my phone right now

Answer (score 0):

In order to get all elements and only add them to the array if the `innerText` is defined, you could loop over each element and decide to add it based on the `innerText`.

Note: I had to add a table element wrapping the `tbody`. This is required anyway as `tbody` has to be a child of `table`.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  
  var cartItems = addAllCartItems();
  console.log(cartItems);
});

var addAllCartItems = function () {
  var array = [];
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#main>#ViewCartWrapper>form>div>.bordered>table>tbody>tr>td");
  
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    if (element.innerText != "") {
      array.push(element.innerText);
    }
  }
  
  return array;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="ViewCartWrapper">
    <form>
      <div>
        <div class="bordered">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>foo</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>bar</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const item = document.querySelectorAll("#main>#ViewCartWrapper>form>div>.bordered>tbody>tr>td");

const filteredCart = Array.from(item).reduce((cart, item, i)=>{
  const innerText = item.innerText;
  if(innerText) cart.push(item.innerText);
  return cart;
}, []);  

console.log(filteredCart);
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <section id="ViewCartWrapper">
    <form>
      <div>
        <table class="bordered">
          <tr>
            <td>Item 1</td>
            <td>Item 2</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </form>
  </section>
</section>
```

You will get the filtered cart with all defined values in filteredCart variable.